# Exporting sites to a new content database

Tags: 2007, export

I have one site collection and it has grown to almost 500GB, i want to move one of our departments to a new site collection. It contains 5 sub-sites and in total about 200GB of content, so the end result is 2 content databases that are fairly manageable in terms of backups and restores.

What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the stsadm -o mergecontentdbs command.  Todd Klindt has an excellent writeup of it at http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=53.  It saved me a ton of headaches.

As always, perform a full backup before making any changes!

Comment: It must be noted that mergecontentdbs, or its powershell command (Move-SPSite), can only be used to move "site collections", so this does not answer the OP: how to move subsites from one site collection to another

Answer (score 10):

- Create a new content database (preferably in a new web application)
- Duplicate existing site collection (as its in a new content database, same internals guids/ids shouldn't clash)

  1. import/export
  2. backup/restore
  3. content deploy
- Trim areas from each site collection that you dont want

If you create a new web application and have the new site collection at the same level (eg '/', rather than '/sites/hr'), you should be able to minimise the amount of broken links (depending on if you have used relative or absolute). People's browser favorities are probably going to be destroyed anyway.

**EDIT**

Some links on the differcens between methods

http://www.venkat.org/2007/10/stsadmin-backuprestore-vs-importexport.html

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sharepointadmin/thread/9d956645-9e92-4a2d-9e0c-17011136c152

And if you have more than 15GB you may need

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc706871(office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks djeeg, do i need to duplicate?, means i need to have enough space for another 500GB db initially, is there no way i can use content deployment to just duplicate the sub-site/s and then trim them off the original site collection. i will probably have '/sites/new', i can change user links via a logon script. what will happen with user accounts and permissions?

Comment: stsadm export can do particular subsites if you need it to, but export/import is not as complete as backup/restore

Comment: you should also remember to lock the site collection before backup / import